# Jmeter - Functional testing log in page

Tags: jmeter

Here is what i am trying to achieve, using Apache JMeter

Submit a request to one of my pages, which will be blocked by Auth filter and redirected to log in page.

1) in the log in page i need to give credentials 
2) upon success it will be redirected to my page ?

How do i test automate the flow using JMeter ?

I am able to achieve till redirect to login page. From there how do i give log in user id and password and resubmit the page so that the entire process is Automated?

Appreciate the help ?

Comment: you mean Browser proxy Authentication?

Comment: No. its intermediate login page

Comment: I was able to achieve this using cookie manager, and submitting the final URL redirect with params.

Comment: post your answer so it will helpful for other.